# Finding a Node in a Document using Xpath

Tags: java, dom, xpath

I have a `Node theFinalNode` from a `Document` which being parsed by a `sax2dom` parser, i have another Document from exactly same page which parsed in different way, i want to find the Node in the other Document using `Xpath`, so i tried to make this code:

```
     private Node node;
 Node theFinalNode;
............

Document document = builder.parse(someURL);
 XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 node =  xpath.evaluate(document,theFinalNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

but it seems there isnt suitable constructor for the way i mentioned above. is there any solution for this?

## error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.xml.xpath.XPath.evaluate
```

## Edit:

```
i changed last line into:`     node =  (Node) xpath.evaluate("//" + theFinalNode.getNodeName(),document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

now the error is:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @UNNI no suitable constructor for Xpath.evaluate(...)

Comment: @UNNI  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.xml.xpath.XPath.evaluate

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the arguments you use in [XPath.evaluate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29)

The first parameter must be an xpath expression (String), the second one is the context and the last one is the return type.
So you can put as first parameter an xpath expression to detect your node (ie. `"//" + theFinalNode.getNodeName()` ), and as second parameter the Document where you want to search for the Node.

Comment: Sorry I assumed the Node was an Element, can you print the output of thefinalNode.getNodeName() and specify the type? So we can help you to create the right xpath expression

Comment: Then you have a Node of type Text, your goal is to find the same text in the other document? Or you want to find the Element containing that text?

Comment: If your node is always of type Text then you can match its containing Element with `"//*[. = \"" + theFinalNode.getNodeValue() + "\"]"`

Comment: i wanna get the exact node in the other document which is of exactly same page, but parsed with different parser. did you understand me?

Comment: With XPath you can get the exact node, just you need to create the correct expression, here you can find a good documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath